# What is window._jqjsp?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I've been looking through some code that rewrites `window._jqjsp`. From the context, it seemed like it was either part of the DOM or something jQuery might insert.

Anyone has a clue what `window._jqjsp` is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's most likely an extension.  I know that a few of the Chrome extensions I use inject scripts on the page.

## EDIT:

After checking around, it looks like this plugin might be assigning itself to that variable.  Are you using [jquery-jsonp?](https://github.com/jaubourg/jquery-jsonp)  [This mentions it.](https://github.com/jaubourg/jquery-jsonp/blob/master/doc/TipsAndTricks.md)

Answer (score 1):

It's used in jQuery mobile development. It looks to be a special type of callback that passes on data to other callbacks.

"The jQuery JSONP plugin provides the sham callback, defaultly named _jqjsp, whose sole purpose is to make the response data available for the app's actual callback functions."

http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/jquery-mobile-listview